# Spring OAuth Filter Chain & Java Config

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to add in spring-security-oauth to an existing app with spring-security. I'm using Java config.

I have an existing amended filter chain in place (with some custom filters added in) but requests to '/oauth/token' aren't using it, but are using the 'default' filter chain. How can i get access to the filter chain that's securing the oauth endpoints so that i can use the custom filters there also or can I wire in the OAuth endpoint(s) into the existing setup?

Comment: Provide spring security oauth2 configuration.

Answer (score 5):

there is indeed a slightly smoother way using the interface `AuthorizationServerConfigurer`.
You can stick to the annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and implement above interface in your configuration file. This will enable you to alter the oauth2-filter-chain by doing something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer
    // some configuration ...

    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthSecurity) throws Exception {
        oauthSecurity.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new YourFilter());
    }

    // more configuration ...
}
```

In contrast to the `addFilterXYX`-methods of `HttpSecurity` you have no fine-grained influence here where the filter will be positioned in the filter chain. Any filter added by `addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter` will be inserted before the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

If you need to control the position of you filter in a more detailed way you could create a bean extending `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` instead of using the annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. I did not try that but I guess you could then extend `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`like systemfreund suggested without having to specify `@Order(-1)` because only your custom configuration gets imported. Probably you would also have to `@Import` `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration`like it is done in the convenience annotation `@EnableAuthorizationServer`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the best way to do it, but I did not manage to find a better approach. The idea is to provide a custom `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` instance and override the default instance which is `@Import`ed via `@EnableAuthorizationServer`. We just need to make sure to add an `@Order` annotation with higher precendence than the default configuration:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Import(CustomSecurityConfig.class)
public class Application {
}

@Configuration
@Order(-1)
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http); // do the default configuration first

        http
            .addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), ...);
    }

}
```